# Creating objects with alphashape3d in R

Tags: r, 3d, volume

I would like to calculate the volume under a surface. My data is similar to the volcano example in R. So I tried to install the alphashape3d package and followed the examples in the manual...

```
# install and load the alphashape3d package
install.packages("alphashape3d")
library(alphashape3d)

# create a torus (see ?ashape3d) and plot it - works
T1 <- rtorus(1000,0.5,2)
ashape3d.obj <- ashape3d(T1,alpha=0.25,pert=T)
plot(ashape3d.obj)

# use the volcano example to create a 3d object - fails
x <- melt(volcano)
ashape3d.obj <- ashape3d(x,alpha=0.25,pert=T)
```

The last line fails:

> Fehler in storage.mode(x) <- "double" :    (list) Objekt kann nicht
>   nach 'double' umgewandelt werden

(Sorry, how can I switch to English in R?)

Why won't it work? `melt(volcano)` is a 3-column-matrix like T1.

Comment: got it: `ashape3d.obj <- ashape3d(as.matrix(x),alpha=0.25,pert=T)`

Answer (score 0):

In case x is a three column something try

```
ashape3d.obj <- ashape3d(as.matrix(x),alpha=0.25,pert=T)
```

If I melt volcano, I get only one column. My volcano is a matrix with 87 rows and 61 columns, rows corresponding to grid lines running east to west and columns to grid lines running south to north.

```
library(raster)
r<-raster(volcano)
library(RSAGA)
v<-grid.to.xyz(z,varname="z")
volcan <- ashape3d(as.matrix(v),alpha=2,pert=T)
plot(volcan, transparency = 0.6,col='black')
```